# How to prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $f(x, y) =\frac{x^p +y^p}{(x+y)^p}\ge C$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $p>1$ and consider the function
$$f(x, y) =\frac{x^p +y^p}{(x+y)^p}\quad\mbox{ for } (x, y)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0, 0\}.$$

It is possible to prove that a positive constant $C$ (which does not depend on $x, y$) exists such that $$f(x, y)\ge C>0?$$

As far as I remember this is a class of functions (maybe called Euler functions, or something like that), which has some particular properties like the one I am trying to prove. If it is the case, could someone please give me a reference?

I am pretty confident that the desired property can be proved assuming $x\neq 0$ (WLOG, since $(x, y)\neq (0, 0)$ and and studying the $1$-variable function $f\left(1, \frac{y}{x}\right)$, but I am looking for something easier (or better, faster).

I hope someone could help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $p>1$ is arbitrary, then you can't consider nonpositive $x,y$. If $x,y>0$, then you can take $C=2^{1-p}$ and use the convexity of $f(t)=t^p$ (i. e. Jensen's inequality).

Comment: @richrow of course since $p>1$ it is $x, y>0$. Thank you for having specified it. Anyway, could you please give more details?

Comment: @richrow also, ho to apply Jensen inequality in 2 variables? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that you already have an idea to study 1-variable function $f(1,y/x)$. Try to set $t = y/x$.

Comment: On $\mathbb R^2$, all norms are equivalent.

Comment: @AnneBauval that's true, but how it applies here?

Comment: The 2 norms $(u,v)\mapsto|u|+|v|$ and $(u,v)\mapsto(|u|^p+|v|^p)^{1/p}$ are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. Could someone please provide a detailed answer? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that,
$$
(|x|+|y|)^p = \|(x,y))\|_1^p \leq (C \|(x,y)\|_p)^p
$$
$$
|x|^p + |y|^p = \|(x,y)\|_p^p.
$$
So,
$$
\dfrac{|x|^p+|y|^p}{(|x|+|y|)^p} \ge \frac{\|(x,y)\|_p^p}{C^p \|(x,y)\|_p^p} = \dfrac{1}{C^p}
$$

The first equality comes from the fact that all norms over a finite dimensional space are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x,y>0$ and $p>1$, we use the following ([equivalence of norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalence)):
$$
\begin{cases}
\|u\|_p\ge \|u\|_2 & p\le 2,\\
\|u\|_p\ge 2^{(\frac1p-\frac12)}\|u\|_2 & p>2,
\end{cases}
$$

Now put $u = (x, y)$, that is, a vector with two dimensions. Then
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=f(u)=\left(\frac{\|u\|_p}{\langle u,\mathbf{1}\rangle}\right)^p\\
&\ge \frac{\|u\|_p^p}{\|u\|_2^p2^{p/2}} \qquad\text{(using Cauchy-Schwarz)}\\
&\ge \begin{cases}
2^{-p/2} & p \le 2\\
2^{1-p} & p > 2
\end{cases}\\
&= C > 0.
\end{align}